# How can I resolve connection issues between my frontend and backend pods in Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, frontend, backend, minikube

I am trying to deploy an application to Minikube. However I am having issues connecting the frontend pod to the backend pod.
Each Deployment have a ClusterIP service, and a NodePort service.

I access the frontend via browser, executing the command: `minikube service frontend-entrypoint`. When the frontend tries to query the backend it requests the URL: *http://fastapi-cluster-ip-service:8000/api/v1/baseline/building_type?building_type=commercial*, but the status response is: *(failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*.

If I access the frontend via cmd, executing the command: `kubectl exec -it react-deployment-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx -- sh`, and execute inside it the command: *curl -X GET "http://fastapi-cluster-ip-service:8000/api/v1/baseline/building_type?building_type=commercial"* I get what I expect.

So, I understand that NodePorts are used to route external traffic to services inside the cluster by opening a specific port on each node in the cluster and forwarding traffic from that port to the service, and that  ClusterIPs, on the other hand, are used to expose services only within the cluster and are not directly accessible from outside the cluster. What I don't understand is why when reaching the frontend via browser, the same is not able to connect internally to the backend? Once playing with the frontend I consider I am inside the cluster...

I tried to expose the cluster using other services such as Ingress or LoadBalancer, but I didn't have success connecting to the frontend, so I rollback to the NodePort solution.

**References:**

- [Kubernetes Guide - Deploying a machine learning app built with Django, React and PostgreSQL using Kubernetes](https://datagraphi.com/blog/post/2021/2/10/kubernetes-guide-deploying-a-machine-learning-app-built-with-django-react-and-postgresql-using-kubernetes)
- [Exposing External-Facing Services In Kubernetes](https://medium.com/hootsuite-engineering/exposing-external-facing-services-in-kubernetes-d27e806d2fc0)

**Files:**

component_backend.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-entrypoint
spec:
  selector:
    component: fastapi
  ports:
  - name: http2
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: fastapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: fastapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fastapi-container
        image: xxx/yyy:zzz
        ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
        env:
          - name: DB_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: app-variables
                key: DB_USERNAME
          [...]
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myregistrykey
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    component: fastapi
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  externalIPs:
    - <minikube ip>
```

componente_frontend.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-entrypoint
spec:
  selector:
    component: react
  ports:
  - name: http1
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: react-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: react
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: react
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: react-container
        image: xxx/yyy:zzz
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: BASELINE_API_URL
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: app-variables
                key: BASELINE_API_URL
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myregistrykey
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: react-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    component: react
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  externalIPs:
    - <minikube ip>
```

BASELINE_API_URL is declared with the backend ClusterIP service name (i.e., fastapi-cluster-ip-service).

ingress_service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sfs.baseline
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend-entrypoint
              port:
                name: http1        
        - path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: backend-entrypoint
              port:
                name: http2
```

Comment: Is the frontend actually running in Kubernetes, or is the React application actually running in the end user's browser?  A browser application will have no knowledge of the Kubernetes environment, and will need to call the backend via some sort of ingress path.

Comment: The frontend is a container inside a pod running in K8S.

Comment: It's using something like a headless Chrome to simulate the browser environment for the React application?

Comment: I don't know, but if I had to bet I would say "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think about this: If you call the api through your browser or Postman from your host, they dont know anything about the url inside your pod.
For production ingress configuration is needed, so you can call the api like:

```
https://api.mydomain.com/api/myroute
```

When you deploy the frontend the paths inside your code should be created dynamically.

Inside your code define the path with env variables and use them inside your code.

On Kubernetes define a configMap with the paths and bind it to your container.
So when you call the Frontend it will have the right paths.

Your Frontend on local can be reached with the Ip address of your masternode and the nodePort.

To not use the ip address you can create an entry in your local hosts file.

```
nodesipaddress  mydomain.local
nodesipaddress  api.mydomain.local
```

so from you browser you can reach the frontend with mydomain.local:nodeportOfFrontend

And your frontend code should call the backend with api.mydomain.local:nodeportOfApi

If you enable Ingress inside your cluster and create an ingress resource in your deployment and a service of type LoadBalancer, then you can call the Frontend and api without the nodePort.

If you are getting in issues with that, please post all your kubernetes yamls. Deployments, Services, configMap and ingress if you decide to use it.

**UPDATE**

Check if you have ingress enabled on minikube

Modify your ingress-recource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
   
kind: Ingress
   
metadata:
   
  name: myingress
   
  annotations:
   
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
   
spec:
   
  rules:
   
    - host: mydomain.local
   
      http:
   
        paths:
   
          - path: /
```

Im not sure if minikube supports ClusterIp

Change the type to LoadBalancer in your service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    component: fastapi
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

If you verify your service:

```
kubectl get svc -o wide
kubectl describe services my-service
```

Look if there is external IP pending if so add externalIp:

```
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  externalIPs: 
    - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # your minikube ip
```

However i would try first to create a service type NodePort and then access with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:NodePort.

In the yamls you posted i see only the backend.

Think if you use ingress or NodePort, your code must be adapted:

Your Frontend must call the api by api ingress domain or xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:NodePort / mydomain.local/api

Comment: what you said helped, however I was not able to make it work... I posted the yamls, if you can again help me I would very much appreciate. With the provided solution I am not able to reach the frontend by accessing via browser the url: `<minikube ip>/`.

Comment: I did an update hope that it can helps you, before ingress i would try to use service type NodePort, so you can be sure you dont have networking issues.

Comment: Thanks again! I was trying to use a component called ['ingress-nginx'](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) instead of the default K8S ingress. About verifying if I have networking issues, I was able to access the frontend using NodePort. I will try now the suggestions you provided.

Comment: I attempted to implement your suggestions (check the code updates). However, I encountered an issue with accessing the frontend. Despite the frontend and backend being similar in structure, I am unable to access the frontend using the same method as the backend, which is: `minikube service backend-entrypoint`, Can you provide any insight on what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Please make a new question and post the frontend deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not understanding how the frontend part of a website works.
To display the website in your browser, you actually download all the required content from the server/pod where you host the frontend.

Once the front is downloaded and displayed on your browser, now you try to hit the backend directly from your browser/computer using either an IP address or an URL.

When using an URL, you browser will try to resolve the hostname using a DNS server

So when you read a website from your browser you are not in the server/pod and you cannot resolve the URL because that URL is not mapped to any IP address (or not to your server).
Also that is why it works when you go inside the pod using `kubectl exec`, because you are inside the network and you are using the internal DNS.

As David said, to make this work, you need to call the backend from the frontend using sone kind of ingress.
And also you will need to create a DNS entry on your domain (if using an URL).
If not you can directly use the IP of the pod/service.

Comment: So, I should remove the NodePort to access the frontend and replace it by an Ingress? Do the same thing for the backend? And add a DNS entry to my domain?

Comment: 1- You dont need a DNS, if you want to use one, then you will need to create the entry and point it to the ingress.
2- You can use NodePort, if so, from the frontend, you will need to reach the back using that NodePort: nodeport:port/route_to_your_api

Comment: Things start to make sense! But just to clarify one last thing, is it necessary to have an Ingress to the frontend and for the backend, or one is enough?

Comment: One is enough. For example the front in: yourwebsite.com/front and your back in yourwebsite.com/back. The ingress will then forward all /front request to the front service and all the /back request to the back service. Here is an example: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43633